# Show multiple Div inside my SharePoint page on the same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint

I am working on a sharepoint 2013 site. where i do not have any control over the pages markup. now if i want to modify the layout, i can write custom css and/or custom javascripts/jQuery.

now i have the following fields , which are being displayed in a new lines, as follow:-

[image]

now i want the fields (Document Type, Departments, Security, etc) to be shown on the same line and not on new lines.

now using Firefox F12 i can inspect the following style for the `idKeyFiltersContainer` Div:-

```
element.style {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 205px;
}
.ms-KFMenu {
    margin: 0;
}
body, .ms-core-defaultFont, .js-callout-body {
    color: #444;
}
body, .ms-core-defaultFont, #pageStatusBar, .ms-status-msg, .js-callout-body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

and the following style for the Div `ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_FilterFormContainer`:-

```
body, .ms-core-defaultFont, .js-callout-body {
    color: #444;
}
body, .ms-core-defaultFont, #pageStatusBar, .ms-status-msg, .js-callout-body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

and the following style for the Divs which have the following class `ms-KFLabelAndBodyContainer` :-

```
.ms-KFLabelAndBodyContainer, .ms-KFHead {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
body, .ms-core-defaultFont, .js-callout-body {
    color: #444;
}
body, .ms-core-defaultFont, #pageStatusBar, .ms-status-msg, .js-callout-body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

so can anyone adivce on this ?
Thanks

**EDIT**
Here is the elements inside a Div:-

[image]

**EDIT-2**:-

here is the full HTML for the parent Div which contain the related fields:-

```
      <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_FilterFormContainer">

        <div class="ms-KFHeadV3 ms-KFHead">
            <h3 id="idKeyFiltersTitle" class="ms-textLarge">Key Filters</h3>
            <div id="idKeyFiltersHeader" class="ms-noWrap">
                <button id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_KeyFiltersApplyAllButton" class="ms-KFButton" onclick="javascript:_mdnSubmitKeyFilters(false); return false;">Apply</button>
                <button id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_KeyFiltersClearAllButton" class="ms-KFButton" onclick="javascript:_mdnSubmitKeyFilters(true); return false;">Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="ms-KFLabelAndBodyContainer">
    <h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-KFLabel">

                <span>Document Type</span>

    </h3>
    <div class="ms-KFBody ms-KFBodyGeneralFilter">
        <span dir="none"><span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl01_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl00"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl01$ctl00$FilterValueControl$ctl00$ctl01" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl01_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl01" type="hidden"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl01_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02" class="ms-taxonomy ms-taxonomy-height ms-long"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl01_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02controlHolder" class="ms-taxonomy-control-holder ms-long"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/EMMCopyTerm.png" title="Browse for a valid choice" alt="Browse for a valid choice" tabindex="0" class="ms-taxonomy-browser-button"><div class="ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor-standard" title="Document Type" style="width: 158px;"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl01_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02editableRegion" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="true" aria-multiline="true" class="ms-rtestate-write ms-taxonomy-writeableregion ms-inputBox" disableribboncommands="True" allowmultilines="false" restrictpastetotext="True" contenteditable="true">​</div></div></div><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl01_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02suggestionsContainer" class="ms-taxonomy-suggestion-container ms-rtefocus-invalid ms-taxonomy-hidden" unselectable="on"><div class="ms-taxonomy-suggestion-holder" unselectable="on"></div><img src="/_layouts/15/images/CornerGrip.gif" unselectable="on" class="ms-taxonomy-panel-resizer"></div></div></span></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ms-KFLabelAndBodyContainer">
    <h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-KFLabel">

                <span>Departments</span>

    </h3>
    <div class="ms-KFBody ms-KFBodyGeneralFilter">
        <span dir="none"><span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl00"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$FilterValueControl$ctl00$ctl01" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl01" type="hidden"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02" class="ms-taxonomy ms-taxonomy-height ms-long"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02controlHolder" class="ms-taxonomy-control-holder ms-long"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/EMMCopyTerm.png" title="Browse for a valid choice" alt="Browse for a valid choice" tabindex="0" class="ms-taxonomy-browser-button"><div class="ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor-standard" title="Departments" style="width: 158px;"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02editableRegion" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="true" aria-multiline="true" class="ms-rtestate-write ms-taxonomy-writeableregion ms-inputBox" disableribboncommands="True" allowmultilines="false" restrictpastetotext="True" contenteditable="true">​</div></div></div><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02suggestionsContainer" class="ms-taxonomy-suggestion-container ms-rtefocus-invalid ms-taxonomy-hidden" unselectable="on"><div class="ms-taxonomy-suggestion-holder" unselectable="on"></div><img src="/_layouts/15/images/CornerGrip.gif" unselectable="on" class="ms-taxonomy-panel-resizer"></div></div></span></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ms-KFLabelAndBodyContainer">
    <h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-KFLabel">

                <span>Customer</span>

    </h3>
    <div class="ms-KFBody ms-KFBodyGeneralFilter">
        <span dir="none"><span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl03_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl00"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl03$ctl00$FilterValueControl$ctl00$ctl01" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl03_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl01" type="hidden"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl03_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02" class="ms-taxonomy ms-taxonomy-height ms-long"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl03_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02controlHolder" class="ms-taxonomy-control-holder ms-long"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/EMMCopyTerm.png" title="Browse for a valid choice" alt="Browse for a valid choice" tabindex="0" class="ms-taxonomy-browser-button"><div class="ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor-standard" title="Customer" style="width: 158px;"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl03_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02editableRegion" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="true" aria-multiline="true" class="ms-rtestate-write ms-taxonomy-writeableregion ms-inputBox" disableribboncommands="True" allowmultilines="false" restrictpastetotext="True" contenteditable="true">​</div></div></div><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl03_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02suggestionsContainer" class="ms-taxonomy-suggestion-container ms-rtefocus-invalid ms-taxonomy-hidden" unselectable="on"><div class="ms-taxonomy-suggestion-holder" unselectable="on"></div><img src="/_layouts/15/images/CornerGrip.gif" unselectable="on" class="ms-taxonomy-panel-resizer"></div></div></span></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ms-KFLabelAndBodyContainer">
    <h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-KFLabel">

                <span>Security</span>

    </h3>
    <div class="ms-KFBody ms-KFBodyGeneralFilter">
        <span dir="none"><span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl00"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$FilterValueControl$ctl00$ctl01" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl01" type="hidden"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02" class="ms-taxonomy ms-taxonomy-height ms-long"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02controlHolder" class="ms-taxonomy-control-holder ms-long"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/EMMCopyTerm.png" title="Browse for a valid choice" alt="Browse for a valid choice" tabindex="0" class="ms-taxonomy-browser-button"><div class="ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor-standard" title="Security" style="width: 158px;"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02editableRegion" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="true" aria-multiline="true" class="ms-rtestate-write ms-taxonomy-writeableregion ms-inputBox" disableribboncommands="True" allowmultilines="false" restrictpastetotext="True" contenteditable="true">​</div></div></div><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02suggestionsContainer" class="ms-taxonomy-suggestion-container ms-rtefocus-invalid ms-taxonomy-hidden" unselectable="on"><div class="ms-taxonomy-suggestion-holder" unselectable="on"></div><img src="/_layouts/15/images/CornerGrip.gif" unselectable="on" class="ms-taxonomy-panel-resizer"></div></div></span></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ms-KFLabelAndBodyContainer">
    <h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-KFLabel">

                <span>Topic</span>

    </h3>
    <div class="ms-KFBody ms-KFBodyGeneralFilter">
        <span dir="none"><span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl00"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl05$ctl00$FilterValueControl$ctl00$ctl01" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl01" type="hidden"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02" class="ms-taxonomy ms-taxonomy-height ms-long"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02controlHolder" class="ms-taxonomy-control-holder ms-long"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/EMMCopyTerm.png" title="Browse for a valid choice" alt="Browse for a valid choice" tabindex="0" class="ms-taxonomy-browser-button"><div class="ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor-standard" title="Topic" style="width: 158px;"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02editableRegion" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="true" aria-multiline="true" class="ms-rtestate-write ms-taxonomy-writeableregion ms-inputBox" disableribboncommands="True" allowmultilines="false" restrictpastetotext="True" contenteditable="true">​</div></div></div><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl02suggestionsContainer" class="ms-taxonomy-suggestion-container ms-rtefocus-invalid ms-taxonomy-hidden" unselectable="on"><div class="ms-taxonomy-suggestion-holder" unselectable="on"></div><img src="/_layouts/15/images/CornerGrip.gif" unselectable="on" class="ms-taxonomy-panel-resizer"></div></div></span></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ms-KFLabelAndBodyContainer">
    <h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-KFLabel">

                Modified

    </h3>
    <div class="ms-KFBody ms-KFBodyRangeCapableFilter">
        <select name="ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl06$ctl00$FilterValueOperatorControl" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl06_ctl00_FilterValueOperatorControl" class="ms-KFOperationDropdown">
        <option value="Eq">On</option>
        <option value="Leq">On or Before</option>
        <option value="Geq">On or After</option>

    </select>
        <span dir="none">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr>
    <td class="ms-dtinput">
    <label for="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl06_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate" style="display:none">Modified Date</label>
    <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl06$ctl00$FilterValueControl$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDate" maxlength="45" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl06_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate" title="Modified" class="ms-input" autopostback="0" type="text"></td>
    <td class="ms-dtinput">
    <a href="#" onclick="clickDatePicker(&quot;ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl06_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate&quot;, &quot;\u002fkb\u002fCustomerServiceKB\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fiframe.aspx?&amp;cal=1&amp;lcid=2057&amp;langid=1033&amp;tz=00:59:59.9998609&amp;ww=0111110&amp;fdow=1&amp;fwoy=0&amp;hj=0&amp;swn=False&amp;minjday=109207&amp;maxjday=2666269&amp;date=&quot;, &quot;&quot;, event);return false;"><img id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl06_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerImage" src="/_layouts/15/images/calendar_25.gif" alt="Select a date from the calendar." border="0"></a></td>
    <td>
    <iframe id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl06_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerFrame" src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" scrolling="no" style="DISPLAY:none;POSITION:absolute; width:200px; Z-INDEX:101;" title="Select a date from the calendar." frameborder="0"></iframe></td>
    </tr></tbody></table>
```

```
<div class="ms-KFLabelAndBodyContainer">
    <h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-KFLabel">

                <span>Modified By</span>

    </h3>
    <div class="ms-KFBody ms-KFBodyUserFilter">
        <span dir="none">
<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl07$ctl00$FilterValueControl$ctl00$HiddenUserFieldValue" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_HiddenUserFieldValue" type="hidden">
<span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField" class="ms-usereditor" editoroldvalue="" removetext="Remove" value="" nomatchestext="<No Matching Names>" allowempty="1" moreitemstext="More Names..." prefercontenteditablediv="true" showdatavalidationerrorborder="false" allowtypein="true" invalidate="false" eeaftercallbackclientscript="" showentitydisplaytextintextbox="0" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl07$ctl00$FilterValueControl$ctl00$UserField$hiddenSpanData" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField_hiddenSpanData" value="&amp;#160;" type="hidden"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl07$ctl00$FilterValueControl$ctl00$UserField$OriginalEntities" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField_OriginalEntities" value="<Entities />" type="hidden"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl07$ctl00$FilterValueControl$ctl00$UserField$HiddenEntityKey" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField_HiddenEntityKey" type="hidden"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl07$ctl00$FilterValueControl$ctl00$UserField$HiddenEntityDisplayText" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField_HiddenEntityDisplayText" type="hidden"><table id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField_OuterTable" class="ms-usereditor" style="border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody><tr valign="bottom">
            <td style="width:88%;" valign="top"><table style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField_containerCell"><div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField_upLevelDiv" tabindex="0" onfocus="StoreOldValue('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField'); saveOldEntities('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField'); Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(this, 'ms-inputBoxActive');" aria-multiline="true" onblur="if(typeof(ExternalCustomControlCallback)=='function'){ if(ShouldCallCustomCallBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField',event)){if(!ValidatePickerControl('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField')){ShowValidationError();return false;}else {ExternalCustomControlCallback('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField');}}} Sys.UI.DomElement.removeCssClass(this, 'ms-inputBoxActive');" class="ms-inputuserfield ms-inputBox" onclick="onClickRw(true, true,event,'ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField');" onchange="updateControlValue('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField');" onpaste="dopaste('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField',event);" prefercontenteditablediv="true" autopostback="0" rows="1" ondragstart="canEvt(event);" onkeyup="return onKeyUpRw('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField');" oncopy="docopy('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField',event);" title="People Picker" onkeydown="return onKeyDownRw('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField', 3, true, event);" spellcheck="false" aria-haspopup="true" style="word-wrap: break-word;overflow-x: hidden;" name="upLevelDiv" role="textbox" contenteditable="true">&nbsp;</div><textarea name="ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl07$ctl00$FilterValueControl$ctl00$UserField$downlevelTextBox" rows="1" cols="20" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField_downlevelTextBox" class="ms-inputuserfield ms-inputBox" onfocus="StoreOldValue('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField'); saveOldEntities('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField'); Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(this, 'ms-inputBoxActive');" onkeyup="return onKeyUpRw('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField');" title="People Picker" onchange="updateControlValue('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField');" onblur="if(typeof(ExternalCustomControlCallback)=='function'){ if(ShouldCallCustomCallBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField',event)){if(!ValidatePickerControl('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField')){ShowValidationError();return false;}else {ExternalCustomControlCallback('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField');}}} Sys.UI.DomElement.removeCssClass(this, 'ms-inputBoxActive');" onkeydown="return onKeyDownRw('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField', 3, true, event);" autopostback="0" renderascontenteditablediv="true" style="width:100%;display: none;position: absolute; "></textarea></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table></td><td style="padding-left:5px;float:right;" valign="top" nowrap="true" align="center"><a id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField_checkNames" title="Check Names" onclick=" if(!ValidatePickerControl('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField')){ ShowValidationError(); return false;} var arg=getUplevel('ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField'); var ctx='ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField';EntityEditorSetWaitCursor(ctx);WebForm_DoCallback('ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl07$ctl00$FilterValueControl$ctl00$UserField',arg,EntityEditorHandleCheckNameResult,ctx,EntityEditorHandleCheckNameError,true);return false;" href="javascript:"><img title="Check Names" src="/_layouts/15/images/checknames.png" alt="Check Names"></a>&nbsp;<a id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField_browse" title="Browse" onclick="__Dialog__ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField(); return false;" href="javascript:"><img title="Browse" src="/_layouts/15/images/addressbook.gif" alt="Browse"></a></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td colspan="3"><span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl07_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField_errorLabel" class="ms-error"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table></span>
```

```
<div class="ms-KFLabelAndBodyContainer">
    <h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-KFLabel">

                Created

    </h3>
    <div class="ms-KFBody ms-KFBodyRangeCapableFilter">
        <select name="ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl08$ctl00$FilterValueOperatorControl" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl08_ctl00_FilterValueOperatorControl" class="ms-KFOperationDropdown">
        <option value="Eq">On</option>
        <option value="Leq">On or Before</option>
        <option value="Geq">On or After</option>

    </select>
        <span dir="none">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr>
    <td class="ms-dtinput">
    <label for="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl08_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate" style="display:none">Created Date</label>
    <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderLeftNavBar$ctl02$ListViewKeyFilters$ctl00$SimpleItemForm$ctl00$ctl08$ctl00$FilterValueControl$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDate" maxlength="45" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl08_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate" title="Created" class="ms-input" autopostback="0" type="text"></td>
    <td class="ms-dtinput">
    <a href="#" onclick="clickDatePicker(&quot;ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl08_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate&quot;, &quot;\u002fkb\u002fCustomerServiceKB\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fiframe.aspx?&amp;cal=1&amp;lcid=2057&amp;langid=1033&amp;tz=00:59:59.9998609&amp;ww=0111110&amp;fdow=1&amp;fwoy=0&amp;hj=0&amp;swn=False&amp;minjday=109207&amp;maxjday=2666269&amp;date=&quot;, &quot;&quot;, event);return false;"><img id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl08_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerImage" src="/_layouts/15/images/calendar_25.gif" alt="Select a date from the calendar." border="0"></a></td>
    <td>
    <iframe id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl08_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerFrame" src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" scrolling="no" style="DISPLAY:none;POSITION:absolute; width:200px; Z-INDEX:101;" title="Select a date from the calendar." frameborder="0"></iframe></td>
    </tr></tbody></table>
```

```
<div class="ms-KFLabelAndBodyContainer">
    <h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-KFLabel">

                <span>Created By</span>

    </h3>
    <div class="ms-KFBody ms-KFBodyUserFilter">
        <span dir="none">
//code removed to minimize charecter count
        <tbody><tr valign="bottom">
            <td style="width:88%;" valign="top"><table style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    //code removed to minimize the charecters
                </tr>
            </tbody></table></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td colspan="3"><span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_SimpleItemForm_ctl00_ctl09_ctl00_FilterValueControl_ctl00_UserField_errorLabel" class="ms-error"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table></span>
```

```
</div>
```

Comment: The styles that put the label and the input on separate lines (that's what you want to change, right?) are likely attached to elements inside those divs - the inputs or labels themselves. Knowing those styles might help, but it might get to be a lot to include in a SO question.

Comment: @arbuthnott can you please check my edit, i provided what is inside the Div.

Comment: looks like you are dealing with a reasonably complicated existing system. I think @amitwadwani gave you a good answer below, including his comment that if it isn't working, it's due to the existing css overriding your changes. sometimes adding `!important` will make sure your new styles are applied and not overridden, but this is generally considered a last resort.

Comment: John - Wanted to ping you here about this https://superuser.com/questions/1243291/copy-documents-from-source-to-destination-sharepoint-libraries-while-preserving as people left you comments and you haven't dropped by SU in a few days and since it's a bounty question, I wanted to send you a quick note while ensuring you get the little red notification that you have messages

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jquery then call following function in document.ready

```
$(".KFLabelAndBodyContainer").css("float:left","width":"x%");
```

width should be 100/(number of container you want in a row)

Above syntax apply float property to class "KFLabelAndBodyContainer"

Or you can directly write below selector for css

```
.KFLabelAndBodyContainer{
float:left;
width:x%;
}
```

Do not forget to apply correct width to containers.

Comment: thanks for your reply.now i tried defining the css you mentioned but it did not have any effect..

Comment: This means some other property overriding this property, Here sequencing of property also matters, Kindly attach full css file and if possible attach html as well

Comment: thanks for the reply again. i edited my original question, and i provided the full HTML for the parent Div which contain the fields i want to relocate them.. thanks